# Conda and Python Modules

Tags: python, ipython, anaconda, conda

Sadly, I do not understand how to install random python modules for use within iPython Notebooks with my Anaconda distribution.  The issue is compounded by the fact that I need to be able to do these things without always using a live internet connection.

Most frequently I run into a problem with gcc compiling, where I can install a module with my basic Python2.7, but not with Conda or with the Anaconda/Python.exe.

- Is Conda only able to install certain modules, as opposed to all valid python modules?
- What is binstar?
- What do I have to do, if anything, to a normal python module in order to make it "Conda-ready," so to speak?
- Once I have downloaded a python module from SourceForge or GitHub or wherever, how can I ask Conda to install that module from the source files  / binary on my computer (without having to connect to the internet)?

Help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Q1: Is Conda only able to install certain modules, as opposed to all valid python modules?

If I understood your question correct, then it is along the lines "How do I get access to all the Anaconda packages"?

**A:** You go online (!), open your cmd.exe or shell and type:

`conda update conda`.

Hit `y+enter` when prompted. When the installer is done, you type:

`conda update anaconda`.

If you get an error in that process, then I would guess your $PATH$ variable needs a check. Google this problem, or `cd` into the anaconda folder and try again. If it still fails, then try downloading the anaconda package from [here](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual) and install it again and press `Y` when prompted to setup Anaconda as default python.

> Q2: What is binstar?

**A:** A package manager. I don't think you need it.

> Q3: What do I have to do, if anything, to a normal python module in order to make it "Conda-ready," so to speak?

**A:** Nothing. You can just run it from the IPython GUI using `%run MyScript.py`

[Here is an example](http://www.packtpub.com/article/ten-ipython-essentials):
Let's write the following Python script in a file called script.py:

```
print("Running script.")
x = 12
print("'x' is now equal to {0:d}.".format(x))
```

Now, assuming we are in the directory where this file is located, we can execute it in IPython by entering the following command:

```
In [1]: %run script.py
Running script.
'x' is now equal to 12.
In [2]: x
Out[2]: 12
```

When running the script, the standard output of the console displays any print statement. At the end of execution, the x variable defined in the script is then included in the interactive namespace, which is quite convenient.

> Q4: Once I have downloaded a python module from SourceForge or GitHub or wherever, how can I ask Conda to install that module from the source files / binary on my computer (without having to connect to the internet)?

**A:** I don't download anything from anywhere manually. If you have to you can use `pip` or `easy_install` when absolute necessary, but before you experiment with these functions, **please start by checking the Anaconda docs** [here](https://docs.anaconda.com/). There are plenty of packages, and I would be surprised if they do not cover your needs.

Comment: binstar is a package *index*, not a package manager. It's a bit like PyPI, but it can host better compiled packages for Conda.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your response.  There are definitely instructions for how to "build" a python module into a Conda-ready module in the Conda documentation and on SO.  Additionally, always connecting to the internet and using pip or easy_install is unfortunately not an option on this machine.  Can you clarify with those restrictions :/ ?

Comment: Once you have the Anaconda package, you don't really need to do much more. Just follow http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install.html. I mean even if the machine is a complete standalone, you can go to another machine and just "install" anaconda on an external USB or drive, so all your stuff is mobile. On my linux, I can move the Anaconda as it suits me. On my windows I could probably too (though I haven't tried).

Comment: If you want to build source modules without internet you need to build them using `Python` included in anaconda binaries `/Users/username/anaconda/bin/python`